# Extending dictionary list values in a certain way

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

Suppose I have a dictionary and I wanted to edit the dictionary lists so that there would be a repetition of values like this.

```
>>> {'hi':[1,2,3,4], 'bye':[5,6,7,8]}
>>> {'hi':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4], 'bye':[5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8]}
```

AND

```
>>> {'hi':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4], 'bye':[5,6,7,8,5,6,7,8]}
```

How would I do this?
I'm assuming you need to use a loop but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension like this

```
d = {'hi':[1,2,3,4], 'bye':[5,6,7,8]}
t = 2
print {k:[j for i in zip(*[v for _ in range(t)]) for j in i] for k, v in d.items()}
print {k:v*t for k, v in d.items()}
```

**Output**

```
{'hi': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], 'bye': [5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8]}
{'hi': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'bye': [5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
```

Comment: What if I needed 3 repetitions, so {'hi': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]}, what would have to be different about my code? And same with {'hi': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]}

Comment: @user3014764 `zip(v, v, v)` and `v+v+v`. :)

Comment: Suppose that the number of repetitions is determined by a variable based on the length of another dictionary list values, for example. {'woah': [1,2,3,4,5]} has a list with a length of 5. I would need 5 repetitions, is there a way I can make this code more general?

Comment: @thefourtheye the first one works, but the second one doesn't, what would I need to change in order to make the second one work?

Comment: @user3014764 Could you please explain why the second one doesnt work?

Comment: @user3014764 I got it now. It was a typing mistake. It should have just `t` instead of `times`. Check that now please.

Comment: I get an error saying "builtins.NameError: name 'data' is not defined"

Comment: Oh yeah, I just fixed that up and changed data into "d", now it works perfectly fine. Thank you so much, I learned a lot!

Comment: @user3014764 The same fault again. Please check now.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

def repeat_whole_list(d, n):
    return {k:list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(v, n))) for k, v in d.items()}

def repeat_items(d, n):
    return {k:[item for item in v for _ in xrange(n)] for k, v in d.items()}
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> repeat_whole_list(d, 2)
{'hi': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'bye': [5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
>>> repeat_items(d, 2)
{'hi': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], 'bye': [5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8]}
>>> repeat_whole_list(d, 3)
{'hi': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'bye': [5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
>>> repeat_items(d, 3)
{'hi': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], 'bye': [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8]}
```

Comment: Oh wow! This works perfectly, thank you so much. But one thing, I don't understand what from itertools import chain, repeat does. Can you explain that please?

Comment: @user3014764 [`repeat`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) repeats the item n times, and then we flatten the iterator returned by repeat using [`chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
>>> d = {'hi':[1,2,3,4], 'bye':[5,6,7,8]}
>>> def duplicate_lists_in_dict(d):
    return {k:v+v for k,v in d.items()}

>>> duplicate_lists_in_dict(d)
{'hi': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'bye': [5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
```

And like this:

```
>>> d = {'hi':[1,2,3,4], 'bye':[5,6,7,8]}
>>> def double_items_in_dict(d):
    return {k:[x for y in zip(v,v) for x in y] for k,v in d.items()}

>>> double_items_in_dict(d)
{'hi': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], 'bye': [5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8]}
```